# Store user input and display

Tags: javascript, html

What the code should do is take in the user input and store in the LocalStorage and then get the input that have been stored and display it. Since is localStorage it should keep the input and display it after closing and opening.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pz9zExrj5o) and tried to modify and fit my what I want to do.
The problem is it doesn't save.

Sorry if this is a bad question

```js
function saveBio() {
  var newBio = document.getElementById("bio").value; //get user input
  localStorage.setItem("storeBio", newBio); //store it

  displayBio(newBio) //take to next function
}

function displayBio(newBio) {

  document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("storeBio");//display the localstorge
 
}
```

```html
<input id="bio" type="text" name="bio" placeholder="Bio" onmouseout=saveBio() ">
```

Comment: change localStorage.getItem(newBio) to localStorage.getItem("storeBio")

Comment: Ahh sorry somehow didn't see that. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this line like that:

```
 document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(newBio); // you need to get the element by providing the Id value
```

document.**getElementById** is a function which takes an Id value to find the matching element and returns it. Then you access the **innerHTML** property of that element and change it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this line in `displayBio()`:

```
document.getElementById.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("storeBio");
```

You're not giving `getElementById` an ID to get - since you want to display the bio, it should be this instead:

```
document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("storeBio");
```

Comment: Well that should be working perfectly now - there's no problem as far as I can see.

Comment: Nope. after refresh it becomes empty again

Comment: Do you need to use localStorage? Surely, you just need one function - and it doesn't really so anything but save the text to storage

Comment: Well anything that can store user input and keep it there between and after sessions without using server or sql. So only thing I saw is localStorage to store data

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood you. The code should still be working perfectly fine though.

Comment: Here is the code updated from feedback "https://jsfiddle.net/hLxmu1ro/6/"

Answer (score 0):

In your getItem function you used the value of the key to get the item.

> The getItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name,
>   will return that key's value or null if the key does not exist.

use ***localStorage.getItem("storeBio")*** instead of ***localStorage.getItem(newBio)***

---

Besides that u must change your ***getElementById*** to: ***document.getElementById("bio")***.innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your don't set and get values in a correct manner.

`localStorage.setItem` accepts 2 arguments as input. (The key and the value)
`localStorage.getItem` accepts 1 argument as the key to retrieve.

Set your item with a key and a value and retrieve it with the key you have specified.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Instead of input i set the key as "storeBio" and the value is user input

Comment: So localStorage.setItem("storeBio", value) and localStorage.getItem("storeBio")

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it as correct